# java update via windows task scheduler

Tags: java, automatic-update, windows-task-scheduler

I want to get rid of always-running jusched.exe, and update java periodically using windows task scheduler. Is it possible?

My system: Windows 8 x64, Java 32-bit

Comment: Why do you want to rid of it? As far as I can tell, jusched.exe hardly burns any CPU at all. It's just sitting there, idle. Are you having performance issues on your computer?

Comment: Well, because I hate all processes running constantly in the background. Windows provides a task scheduler - any software which requires auto update should make use of it, instead of adding an extra process of its own.

Comment: Hate is a strong word. Many things running in the background are usually harmless, some are even essential. It's a myth that all programs need to be terminated when not in use - sometimes doing so will only make things worse. There are situations where memory-resident programs make your experience better. Of course, it doesn't mean you have to let anything and everything running in the background - but find the right balance. Hence my question, do you have performance issues on your computer? (About task scheduler, it doesn't always work as you intend & hardly any program uses it for updates.)

Comment: I've had my computer on for almost 2 days, and `jusched` did not burn even a second's worth of CPU. Dropbox on the other hand burned 3 hours, Chrome 1.5 hours, `explorer` 1+ hours. I really think you have more important things to worry about. But have you tried this?: http://superuser.com/a/419550/117986

Comment: I'm a little bit horrified that there's a comment asking "Why do you want to do that ... " on a stack exchange site. Seriously?

Comment: @ADTC Well, at the moment I'm not having performance issues on my computer, but as they say, nip the evil in the bud. I would like to suppress extra background apps now rather than several months later when there would be too many useless processes slowing down my  computer. And the statement "hardly any program uses it for updates" is not true - two major programs that use task scheduler are Adobe Flash and Google Chrome.

Comment: Turns out that I'm not alone thinking alone these lines. Someone else already asked [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/443686/silent-java-update-check). Unfortunately the script given in the [answer](http://superuser.com/a/443687/137255) is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Java updates are going through an especially bad phase at the moment (check this article: http://www.zdnet.com/a-close-look-at-how-oracle-installs-deceptive-software-with-java-updates-7000010038/).

It's reasonable to find it naggy and annoying.

Yet keeping up with security updates is so important I'm not even going to bother justifying it.

Also `jusched` cannot be uninstalled by mortals, many have tried for years, I don't know anyone who's succeeded. It's profoundly embedded with your Java installation.

Therefore the ultimate solution is: **uninstall Java**.

Obviously you may not want to do this and a secondary work-around might be to use a service like `Ninite` to keep updated then despite `jushed.exe` always running it will never get to the aggravating and insidious "Java Update Available" stage and (as mentioned by our esteemed peers in the comments) it uses effectively no resources.

Comment: Uninstalling java is not an option for those who rely on desktop java applications. I am in favor of keeping java _plugin_ disabled in the primary browser. The Ninite suggestion is good, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree Java shouldn't run constantly for a monthly check. However, it's configuration is also misleading. When you disable the monthly check just run [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and you will see it still configured to load every time you boot the system. [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) may also be useful to verify what is actually running on your rig.

Solution is to use Task Scheduler as explained [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-juschedexe-and-why-is-it-running/).

Comment: Can you summarize that howtogeek link, so that in case if it goes dead, your answer is still useful?