# Is there a way to stop Java from continually running in background?

Tags: windows-7, java

When Java is installed on a Windows system, is there a way to keep it from running continually in the background?

I would like it to be launched only when I specifically need it or use it, not all the time. For example only when the associated Java plugin is called by a web browser.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have java installed, it is currently not running, because I have no Java applications running.  If Java is running in the background then some application is using the Java VM, Java will not run in the background unless a java application is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed regular Java (Java Runtime Environment), the only process which is running per default in the background is `jusched.exe` (Java Update Scheduler). This process just looks for Java updates. If you click on the *Update* tab of the *Java Control Panel* you will see this option:

> ☑ Check for Updates Automatically

However, for most people automatically looking for updates is highly recommended, as they often fix security issues. If unchecking it does not hinder `jusched.exe` from starting, you might want to try some of the hints provided here: [How to disable jusched.exe on Windows 7 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/241147/how-to-disable-jusched-exe-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to open Task Manager, switch to the "Startup" tab and change the java update program from enabled to disabled. That will take effect starting next time you boot your computer.